# How to build and work with lists of 30M or more elements?

Tags: python, python-3.x, collections, counter, ram

I'm trying to count the frequency of words in some documents.
For filtering / cleaning I'm using [SpaCy](https://spacy.io/models/en#en_core_web_md).

```
from collections import Counter

nouns = []
length = 0
for sentence in sentences:
    for token in sentence:
        if token.pos_ == "NOUN":
            if token.is_stop is False and not token.is_punct and not token.is_digit and not token.like_num and len(token) >= 4:
                nouns.append(token.text)
                length += 1

noun_freq = Counter(nouns)
common_nouns = noun_freq.most_common()
```

When I run this script on a few thousands or a million words, it just does what it's supposed to do. (Get the most common nouns).

When I use above 10 million words, my kernel kills the script and shows that it's out of memory.

from the syslog:

```
kernel: [458254.437276]  oom_kill_process.cold+0xb/0x10
kernel: [458254.437278]  out_of_memory.part.0+0x1df/0x3d0
kernel: [458254.437280]  out_of_memory+0x6d/0xd0
```

Which other ways are there, to count / get frequencies of most common words for a few dozen millions of words?

Comment: Seems like you could split the document into chunks, and process that way

Comment: I'm not sure what your data looks like and what you're trying to achieve, but likely a vectorized approach in `pandas` would be more efficient.

Comment: How is `sentences` constructed? Do you actually need `nouns` other than to pass to Counter()?

Comment: How many distinct words do you anticipate?

Comment: Why not use a "helper" memory like `sqlite` or some file to store results, rather buffer all to the memory?

Comment: Not sure how many distinct words the outcome would bring. A few thousand?
Maybe `sqlite` is a good idea, thanks for that.